# Environment Variables not picked up by code through plist

Tags: ios, xcode

In my main target `.plist` file I have this:

```
<key>HIHomePage</key>
<string>$(MY_BASE_URL)</string>
```

I'm using a build schema per each environment I have (development, staging, production), so I set `MY_BASE_URL` in Environment Variables in the build step of the schema.

Then in code I have this:

```
NSString *baseURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"HIHomePage"];
```

That turns out to be an empty string, however stuff such as `CFBundleName` is being picked up.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get values from environment variables use the following code

```
NSString *baseURL = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"MY_BASE_URL"];
```

Ref : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Environment_variables#Objective-C

To add items in plist from scheme, you should dd a user defined build settings with name `MY_BASE_URL` and enter values as per your scheme. Then use it in `.plist` file.

For adding user defined build settings,
Select target
From Editor menu > Add Settings > User defined Settings

Comment: do you suggest moving the dev, staging, production config to targets instead of schemas?

Comment: No No, you can set build settings according to configurations/schema will update the answer